# iOS : Black screen appears when run my app

Tags: ios, swift

Actually [image]When I run my iOS app and it’s get black screen like this .  I deleted scene delegate file and function from appdelegate but it’s still shows black screen . Any Idea??

Comment: which version of xcode you are using ?

Comment: xcode 12.5 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:-
you need to remove the dependency of scene delegate from info.plist
(follow Step show in above Ans of Dipak Ramoliya)

Step 2:-
comment code in scene delegate file

step 3:-
comment code related to scene delegate in App delegate file (connectingSceneSession method and sceneSessions method)

step 4:- Add window variable in AppDelegate file (var window: UIWindow?)

step 5:- create rootViewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in App Delegate

ex:-

```
let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testController") as! TestController
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = testController
```

Comment: This is showing an error and not working… (“as! TestController”) connot find TestController in scope

Answer (score 2):

[image]you need to follow 2 steps :

1. first check that you deleted Appmanifest Key from your info.plist file And if you don’t then first delete it I attach reference image for you and

2.Check your minimum iOS target is 13 or not if 13.0 then you can change it to 11.0

Hope your issue will resolve using this 2 steps.